# Copy a firestore document to another collection from firebase trigger function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to sync my doc to another collection based on the `firebase trigger function`

```
exports.foo = functions
  .region("foo")
  .firestore.document("foo")
  .onWrite((events, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (events.after.exists) {
        // on create or update
        admin
          .firestore().doc("newFoo")
          .set(events.after.data)
          .then(() => { resolve(true); })
          .catch((ex) => { reject(ex); });
      } else{
        // on delete
        admin
          .firestore()
          .doc("newFoo")
          .delete()
          .then(() => { resolve(true); })
          .catch((ex) => { reject(ex); });
      }
    });
  });
```

but I got the following error when I try to manually edit my document in firestore

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document.
> Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

why do I get the error? as I check, the `events.after.data` is also returning a `FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData` which is the correct data type for `doc.set()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `.set(events.after.data)` should be `.set(events.after.data())` as data is a method not a property.